# How to set focus on a textbox when I close another Form?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have two forms, Form1 and Form2. Form2 is opened from a button located in Form1. All I want is that when I close Form2 from X(cross) button in the upper right corner of the window, the focus is set to textbox1 of a Form1. Any help regarding this ??

Comment: Is `Form2` opened as modal from `Form1`?

Comment: I use this method to open the Form2.
Form2 obj= new Form2();
obj.show();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.Show();
        f.FormClosed += f_FormClosed;

    }

    void f_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
         textBox1.Focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Write this code in `form1` `button click` event:

```
form2 fm2 = new form2();
fm2.ShowDialog();     //to show as child form of Form1

textbox.Focus();    //as Form2 closes it will focus to your textbox now
```

Comment: The OP doesn't use `ShowDialog`, but `Show`.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign an event handler to `form2`'s `Close` event manually like this:

```
form2 = new Form2();
form2.Closed += Form2Closed;
form2.Show();

public void Form2Closed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Focus();
}
```

Please note that this works in your case, as you're not showing `form2` with `ShowDialog`!

Also, this sets the focus if the form is closed by some other way, too, for example a button on the form. If you really only want to focus the text box if the close box of the window is clicked, you need to do a bit more.

```
public void Form2Closed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
    {
        Form2 f2 = sender as Form2;
        if (!f2.ClosedByUserElement)
            textBox2.Focus();
    }
}
```

Also, in `Form2` you need a property `ClosedByUserElement` which is normally `false`, but set to `true` whenever the user closes the form by other means than the red `X`, for example a button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClosedByUserElement = true;
    Close();
}
```

That way you can decide whether the user closed the window using the window's close box (`ClosedByUserElement` would be `false`) or by a manual call to `Close`, for example when a button is clicked (`ClosedByUserElement` would be `true`).

Answer (score 0):

if `Form2` is a modal form opened with `ShowDialog()` method, you can simply add this code in Form1 button Click event, after the form opening:
    `this.textbox1.Focus();`

Answer (score 0):

Write this Code in Form1's Button Click Event by which button you open the Second Form

```
         Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
         frm2.ShowDialog(); // do what you want in your form, then close it

         yourTextbox.Focus();
         yourTextbox.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;  // instead of LightYellow Write whatever colour you want
```

Hope this Helps You ....

Answer (score -1):

You can use the other form load event if it is opened from one parent form directly, or use cases for the parent forms if you want to change the focused textbox.